# Select only rows containing numbers

Tags: t-sql, wildcard

I have data containing following strings as:

```
Hello | World | 40
Hi | World | 24244
One | Two | 27
This | That | 84f
Yes | No | 456gf
The | Test|54
```

Now I need to write query to get only those rows, where are only numbers in the end, filtering those with characters behind them. Result of the above set:

```
Hello | World | 40
Hi | World | 24244
One | Two | 27
The | Test|54
```

I tried several approaches using wildcards but with not success.

```
TB LIKE '%_|_[0-9]%' OR TB LIKE '%_|[0-9]%' 
AND TB NOT LIKE '%[0-9][^a-z]%'
```

and so on. Obviously e.g. this query returns also the rows containing 456gf and 84f.

Comment: If you only want to be sure that the last character is a number and not a letter then you could use `isnumeric(right(string,1)) = 1` or you could test the whole substring after the last pipe. Be aware that isnumeric returns true for some symbols too (+ - $ for instance)

Comment: @jpw - OP could even use `TB LIKE '%[0-9]'` as a way to check the last character of the string to be an int without the querks of `isnumeric`

Comment: @ughai Ah, right. That would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there. 
I'm not sure if you mean _ or space in your pattern.
I think the main problem is that the "NOT ^" trick isn't working as expected. You really only want it to apply to the last section.

Try this as your WHERE...

```
LTRIM(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(TB),1,CHARINDEX('|',REVERSE(TB)) - 1))) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

try with cte,

```
    declare @t table (field1 varchar(20),field2 varchar(20),field3 varchar(20) )
insert into @t
        ( field1, field2, field3 )
values  ('Hello','World','40')
        ,('Hi', 'World','24244')
        ,('One','Two','27')
        ,('This', 'That','84f')
        ,('Yes','No','456gf')
        ,('The','Test','54')
;with cte as(
select *, CASE ISNUMERIC(field3) WHEN 1 THEN CAST(field3 AS int) ELSE null end as Field4
from @t)
SELECT cte.field1,cte.field2,cte.field3 FROM cte
where field4 is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

use try_parse insted of isnumeric because it's quicker than ISNUMERIC.

```
declare @t table (field1 varchar(20),field2 varchar(20),TB varchar(20) )
insert into @t
        ( field1, field2, TB )
values  ('Hello','World','40')
        ,('Hi', 'World','24244')
        ,('One','Two','27')
        ,('This', 'That','84f')
        ,('Yes','No','456gf')
        ,('The','Test','54')
;
Select * from @t 
WHERE  TRY_PARSE(Tb as int) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This should meet your requirements (the table is called t, the column c):

```
select * from t where isnumeric(substring(c, charindex('|', c, charindex('|', c, 0) + 1) + 1, len(c))) = 1
```

The inner charindex `charindex('|', c, 0)` finds the position of the first pipe symbol, the outer one finds the position of the second, because it starts its search behind the first one. After that, the isnumeric checks whether the remainder is indeed a number. To test:

```
declare @t table(c varchar(100))
insert into @t (c) values 
(' Hello | World | 40'),
('Hi | World | 24244'), 
('One | Two |  27    '),
('This | That | 84f '), 
('Yes | No | 456gf  '), 
('The | Test|54     ') 

select charindex('|', c, charindex('|', c, 0) + 1), charindex('|', c, 0) from @t
select * from @t where isnumeric(substring(c, charindex('|', c, charindex('|', c, 0) + 1) + 1, len(c))) = 1
```